# exe file on QT hang when update time on raspberry pi terminal

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi

I have exe file on qt that running on raspberry pi terminal. For several time, i update my raspberry pi time with 'sudo date -s "Thu Jun 09 10:11:00 2016"'. At first, it is looked alright. But after i do this for many time, my exe file is not working. Anyone know? why is this happened to my exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Without source code noone can say *why* this happens, but here's a guess *how*:

A future timestamp is calculated from the current time/datetime, and some part of the app waits for that time to arrive. Skipping the system clock forward over that timestamp will hopefully match the condition (if the coder was smart enough to test for `futureTime <= now`, not only for equality), but skipping it backwards will probably make the app wait for an unexpected long time until the condition matches again.

Fix: Use (monotonic) timers instead of calculated times to test conditions and schedule events. See `QTimer` and `QTime` as well as the general doc about [Qt timers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/timers.html).